# How to send video live stream to azure cloud?

Tags: java, android, azure, azure-media-services

I search for suitable service that I can use in this case: 
open camera in video mode and stream it to the azure cloud.
and from other side listen to it (also clients). 
I read about Azure Media services. 
but according [this](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/azure/en-US/966fb556-f640-4844-a53a-0e801082a1eb/azure-media-service-integrating-on-ios-and-android-project?forum=MediaServices) I Understand that it is not allow from the client side. 
does have other way to workaround or other service that I can use?

Comment: I am not a 100% sure, but I believe your mobile app will need to use OBS studio, then send it to Azure Media Services

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you share more details on the use case scenario? 
If I understand your request above, you are looking for a way to build an Android application that can use the local device camera and push the stream to Azure Media Services, and view it on another device? 
Is that the use case scenario?

That is certainly possible, but you would need an application that is capable of sending RTMP protocol.  There are a number of 3rd party libraries out there that can send RTMP.

The article that you linked to was responded to by me, and what I was pointing out there is that you should try not to store any of your Azure Media Services account credentials inside a phone app.  You should use a middle tier to authenticate the app user, and provide the app with the appropriate RTMP ingest URL for a Live Event.

Comment: thank you on your response. Yes, It is exactly the scenario. Do you have 3rd library recommended? also when it is need to store credentials for example? in which scenarios? is it necessary in my case? also is it possible to work with ams and to wrap it into android library?

Comment: I dont have a recommended 3rd party library - there are many out there, but I have never tested any of them direclty. 
You will need to store the AAD application client id and secret used to access the API someplace.  Make sure that is secured - and dont ship it with any app code directly ever.